# Why does the compiler require return type in the following lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, types

I am implementing recursive DFS as a lambda passing itself as a parameter. If I comment out the logic that checks if the current node has no children, I get build errors saying that the lambda is used before type deduction.

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int root;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph;

    // ...
    // build the tree as adjacency list starting from root
    // ...

    auto dfs = [&graph](auto self, auto u) {
        // if (empty(graph[u])) {
        //     return;
        // }
        for (auto v : graph[u]) {
            self(self, v);
        }
    };

    dfs(dfs, root);
}
```

```
/usr/bin/g++-10 -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -g -o main main.cpp
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘main()::<lambda(auto:44, auto:45)> [with auto:44 = main()::<lambda(auto:44, auto:45)>; auto:45 = int]’:
main.cpp:66:18:   required from here
main.cpp:63:17: error: use of ‘main()::<lambda(auto:44, auto:45)> [with auto:44 = main()::<lambda(auto:44, auto:45)>; auto:45 = int]’ before deduction of ‘auto’
   63 |             self(self, v);
      |             ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

However, once I have that check-if-empty logic back, the code compiles with no issues.

Is that because in the latter case, the `return` statement gives the compiler a hint that the lambda returns `void` and therefore, its type is known at the time `self(self, v)` is called?

More broadly, where can I read and learn more about how compilers process lambda definitions to avoid relying on their error messages and know when it's necessary to declare the return type and when it's not?

Comment: What is `vector`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I see infinitive recursion of dependency. Calling `dfs` depends on caling `dfs`. To know tpye of fist argument you need to know its type. To much `auto`-s.

Comment: IMO it would be better to create a class and drop lambda. It would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `return;` statement is exactly what tells the compiler the return type of the lambda. In this example, the statement says the function return `void`.

Without knowing the return type, the call to `self(self, v);` is ill-formed, since you're effectively relying on `auto` being deduced without giving the compiler a way of figuring it out.

The language explicitly mentions this example in [dcl.spec.auto#general-11](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#general-11):

> If a variable or function with an undeduced placeholder type is named by an expression ([basic.def.odr]), the program is ill-formed. **Once a non-discarded return statement has been seen in a function**, however, **the return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the function**, including in other return statements.

(emphasis mine), and provides a simpler version of the problem in your code:

> ```
> auto sum(int i) {   
>   if (i == 1)
>     return i;              // sum's return type is int   
>   else
>     return sum(i-1)+i;     // OK, sum's return type has been deduced 
> }
> ```

Comment: This is incomplete/wrong. The auto deduced fine. dfs has a concrete deduced type and of course self is dependent and can be mentioned in the way it is. The problem is that the call expression in the lambda (with all the concrete substituted types) instantiates the call operator and the deduction of its return type is what fails (being dependent on the compound expression which is the lambda body, which is dependent on the call operator). You can also just specify the return type. `-> void`.

Comment: It's not incomplete/wrong, the `auto` indeed didn't manage to deduce the types because the function was invoked before anything was provided for the compiler to deduce the return type. In the example you can see that `return i` is present before the function is called recursively, hence, the compiler knows that `sum` returns `int` and can properly process `return sum(i-1)+i`. If you change the order of the if statements you will see compiler errors.

Comment: In my example, it's pretty clear that `auto` in the declaration of `dfs` refers to the return type of the lambda, or to be more precise, the return type of the call operator, but that's all the same from the perspective of deducing `auto`.